# Scheme: Getting cdr without the parens

Tags: scheme, racket, let, cdr

This is probably a simple thing I'm missing, but I'm trying to get the `cdr` of a pair and every call to say `(cdr (cons 'a '5))` comes back as `(5)`. I sort of get why that is, but how can I get the it to return without the parens?

I don't want to use `flatten` because what I'm trying to get (i.e. the cdr) might itself be another procedure expression already wrapped in parens, so I don't want to flatten the list.

(If it matters, I'm working on transforming a `let` expression into a `lambda` expression, and this is one of the steps I'm taking, trying to break apart the lambda bindings so I can move them around).

Comment: "(cdr (cons 'a '5)) comes back as (5)" No, it doesn't. The result of `(cdr (cons 'a '5))` is `5`, not `(5)`, i.e. exactly what you want. Your problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: @sepp2k Hmm, well I'm seeing behaviour like what's defined here http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._cdr)) (See the example) and I'm just trying to figure out how I might solve that. Do you have any suggestions how I might achieve what I'm trying to do (i.e. flatten just the first level)?

Comment: @jbrennan That example is different. `(cdr '(a 5))` would return `(5)`, of course, because `'(a 5)` is a list (i.e. a pair whose `cdr` is a list). `(cdr (cons 'a 5)` however definitely returns `5`. Note that calling `(cadr (cons 'a 5))` would result in an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When applied to a proper list, `cdr` will always return another list (including `'()`, the empty list).

With *proper list* I mean a list which ends with the empty list. For instance, when you do this `(define lst '(4 5))` under the hood this is what gets assigned to `lst`: `(cons 4 (cons 5 '()))`, so when you evaluate `(cdr lst)` you get the *second* element of the first `cons`, which happens to be `(cons 5 '())`, which in turn gets printed as `(5)`.

For extracting only the second element in the *list* (not the second element of the first `cons`, which is what `cdr` does) you could:

1. As has been pointed in the comments, use `(car (cdr lst))` or just `(cadr lst)` for short
2. Even simpler: use `(second lst)`
3. Another possibility - if the list only has two elements and it's ok to replace it with an improper list, use `(define cell (cons 4 5))` or `(define cell '(4 . 5))` to build a cons cell and then you can use `(car cell)` to extract the first element and `(cdr cell)` to extract the second element.

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer to my question instead of pointing out a minute pedantic technical error in my question. I really appreciate it! :)